# Read, compose and send zimbra emails from vim

Tags: plugin-system, clientserver

I live most of my working hours inside vim.
My institution uses an email client server provided by [zimbra](https://www.zimbra.com/). The email domain starts with `zimbra***inst.fr.`
Is there a way to read, compose and send emails from vim?

Answer (score 1):

Try [mutt](http://www.mutt.org) which can open mails in vim.

Comment: Would also be my suggestion. Also you can open the mail text in vim over the webinterface if you have vimperator for firefox